# Stop div fixed positioning when scrolled away

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript/jQuery code that takes a div with the id page_block_422 that is located further down the page, and it applies fixed positioning using a class to make it stay to the top of the window once I have scrolled past it, and when I scroll back to the top it remains in place. 
The issue im having is that, there are other DIVs below it  and the fixed positioning makes it hover over them.

What I've tried

jQuery:

```
    var s = $("#page_block_422");
    var pos = s.position();
    var newWidth = s.parent().width();
    //s.addClass("stick");
    s.css("width", newWidth - 10 + "px");


$(window).scroll(function(){
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();

if (windowpos > pos.top) {
    s.addClass("stick");
    s.css("top",Math.max(0,860-$(this).scrollTop()));
    s.css("position","fixed");

} else {
    s.removeClass("stick");
    s.css("position","relative");
}
```

CSS:

```
.stick {
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 999;
    width: inherit;
}
```

I've changed the operator around to >=, <=, < in the if function to get different results as well.

Any help on this would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A fiddle worth a thousand words.

Comment: and in the html for the fiddle type `lorem*50` and press tab (to let us scroll).

Comment: how could it stay at the top of the screen and not hover over the remaining content?

Comment: The DIV itself is further down the page, so when I scroll over it is when it gains fixed positioning. I know it's supposed to hover over the remaining content but my intention is when I scroll back to the top of the page that the DIV returns to its original state of being relative and aligned properly until scrolled to again, if that makes any sense? You can see what I mean here, in the right column: http://cooltopics.com/community/index.php

Comment: Could you use the jQuery waypoints plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using else, just write another if.

```
if (windowpos > pos.top) {
    s.addClass("stick");
    s.css("top",Math.max(0,860-$(this).scrollTop()));
    s.css("position","fixed");

} 
if (windowpos < pos.top) {
    s.removeClass("stick");
    s.css("position","relative");
}
```